# Right triangle using nested for loop python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to output a right triangle with numbers. Here is what I have so far:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(i):
    print(i, end='')
print()
```

My output is this

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

My question is this.  Can I make these numbers run in sequence using a nested for loop
example:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
```

I've tried about 6 other sets and mostly keep getting the same output or multiple errors.  Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider what happens next? This gives you a few ideas.

```
import itertools

for i in range(1, 21):
    cycle = itertools.cycle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
    for j in range(i):
        print(next(cycle), end="")
    print()
```

This cycles through the digits giving you output as follows:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
1234567890
12345678901
123456789012
1234567890123
12345678901234
123456789012345
1234567890123456
12345678901234567
123456789012345678
1234567890123456789
12345678901234567890
```

Or alternatively:

```
for i in range(1, 21):
    for j in range(i):
        print(((j % 10) + 1) % 10, end="")
    print()
```

Comment: This works out perfectly.  Like I said I'm still new to this language now I see in yours that 0 is actually coming up.  How does that work out? because anytime I try to run 0 as part of my range I always start off with 1 instead of 0 like I'm trying for

Comment: The first example just cycles through the digits, the second one makes use of the `%` modulus operator to give a remainder, e.g. `12 % 10 = 2` and `0 % 10 = 0`, so add 1 and it would then cycle from `1` to `10`, another `%` would make it cycle `1` to `0`.

Comment: I was just getting ready to post back to you that I had figured that portion out. Thank you so much for your help on this now its starting to make a little more sense.

Comment: so out of curiosity why is it when I try to run a set of higher numbers in stepped count
i.e.

                10
        11 12
        13 14 15
        16 17 18 19

I tried to change around the variables but either get the exact printing as before or it prints nothing but 0's. possibly need to build up a library of some type? not sure  how yet but ill do some more reading tomorrow when I have the chance

Comment: apologies for blowing up your feed I found where my problem was after I started reading through it again. in the mad rush to develop the loop code I totally had a blond moment and forgot to add height variable into the final equation.  As soon as that was input it took straight off

Answer (score 1):

`j` can do more than a counter:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(i):
        print(j + 1, end='')
    print()
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I can see where I need to reread a number of sections I had to have missed this